# How to resolve 'Python issue: Failed to resolve compatible distributions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-vision, pants

I'm facing the following issue when running my Python code in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
Exception message: 1 Exception encountered:
 
ProcessExecutionFailure: Process 'Building requirements.pex…'

stderr:
Failed to resolve compatible distributions:
1: grpcio-status==1.62.0 requires protobuf>=4.21.6 but protobuf 3.20.3 was resolved
```

I don't have experience with Python but I believe it could be related to the use of google-cloud-vision 2.3.1. For more info, grpcio 1.39.0 (not grpcio-status) and protobuf 3.17.3 were found in the lambda file (from when it was last working).

Does anyone have a solution?

Previously, I tried specifying dependency versions in the BUILD file and in a requirements.txt file in the root (which doesn't usually exist). There was no change.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that grpcio-status requires protobuf version 4.21.6 or above. You can try to specify the version using a writing method similar to grpcio-status==4.21.6.